# Is it possible to use a variable as the fill argument in the format! macro?

Tags: rust, formatting, fill

I wanted to imitate Python's `rjust`, `ljust`, and `center` functions using the `format!` macro, but I was only able to work out a solution where you can pass in the string and the width. If you want to pass in the fill-argument it doesn't work.

The documentation tells me that it is possible to provide variables to `format!` and for the width argument it works just fine. When I try to use a variable for fill, the compiler does not recognize the pattern.

Just the width as a variable works:

```
fn rjust(text: &str, width: usize, fill: Option<char>) -> String {
    format!("{text:>width$}", text = text, width = width)
}
println!("{}", rjust("Hello", 10)); // "     Hello"
```

Providing the fill as a variable does not work:

```
fn rjust(text: &str, width: usize, fill: char) -> String {
    format!(
        "{text:fill>width$}",
        text = text,
        fill = fill,
        width = width
    )
}
println!("{}", rjust("Hello", 20, '*'));
```

The error message:

```
error: invalid format string: expected `'}'`, found `'>'`
 --> src/lib.rs:4:24
  |
4 |             "{text:fill>width$}",
  |              -         ^ expected `}` in format string
  |              |
  |              because of this opening brace
  |
  = note: if you intended to print `{`, you can escape it using `{{`
```

If I provide a single character instead of the fill-variable, it works fine. Notice the `*` character:

```
fn rjust(text: &str, width: usize, fill: char) -> String {
    format!("{text:*>width$}", text = text, width = width)
}
println!("{}", rjust("Hello", 20, '_')); // ***************Hello
```

I expected the fill-variable version to work the same as the hardcoded `*` character version.

A workaround is to subtract the length of the text from the width and then create a `String` of that length (fill-length) made of fill-characters and  concatenate them:

```
fn rjust(text: &str, width: usize, fill: char) -> String {
    let fill_len = width - text.len();
    let fill_str: String = (0..fill_len).map(|_| fill).collect();
    String::from(fill_str + text)
}
println!("{}", rjust("Hello", 20, '*')); // ***************Hello
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no built-in way to do this.

The formatting syntax evolved with features that early Rust adopters needed at the time. Its terseness means that new features are [very difficult to add after the fact](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9669#issuecomment-25505018).