# How do I format a string using a fill character from a named argument?

Tags: string, rust, format

How can I use the named argument `ch` as the fill character? For example, with this code:

```rust
println!("{:_^width$}", "ABC", width = 7, ch = '_');
```

I want this output:

```
__ABC__
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is it possible to use a variable as fill-argument in the format! macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56666258/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Yes that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately we can't mark this as a duplicate because the linked question is unanswered. You'll need to close this yourself @mazznoer 